# Display .pgm image file on apache webserver

Tags: images, apache-http-server, conversion

I have a .pgm image file that I'd like to display on my apache webserver. Right now when I try to display it, it fails. Is there a way to configure apache so that I can display it successfully on a browser? I've tried searching but I haven't found anything useful.

If not, what can I use to convert the .pgm image file into another format, say .jpg, and then display the .jpg image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether it will render ultimately depends on the browser, however I believe the "magic sauce" you are missing to make it work from the server side is that you need to specify the mime type.

There are a few ways to do this but generally Apache reads the file /etc/mime.types 
You need to ensure the line "image/x-portable-graymap                        pgm" is added to this file so it serves the image up correctly.

The alternative would be some kind of script and cgi to convert it using the netpbm library or something like that.  (I've not used it, but it looks like you can use pgmtoppn  and then ppntopng to convert a file to a jpg)

Comment: Adding `image/x-portable-graymap pgm` to /etc/mime.types doesn't work. If possible, I'd really much prefer this over having to convert the image to another format.